# AppDomain.AssemblyResolve fired when loading mscorlib.resources.dll

Tags: .net, assemblies

According to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx), `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` occurs when the resolution of an assembly fails. In my application, it is fired when it tries to load `mscorlib.resources`.

As this assembly is located in GAC, how can I fix this issue?

Comment: It is not located in the GAC, it doesn't exist.  You must ignore AssemblyResolve requests for assemblies that you don't know how to load.

Comment: This was my first workaround, so I will keep it. Thanks.